# How to disable change password on phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, debian

I need to disable or hide change password on main settings phpmyadmin in epitome users should not change password.

How can i modify this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide the phpMyAdmin change password with the following line in the config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['ShowChgPassword']=false;
```